# html5 microdata markup using Schema.org

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I am working on a site of a christian church. It has a page with schedule list and house churches list which I want to mark up using Schema.org microdata. The thing is I cannot find appropriate type to describe these items. For schedule I decided to go for http://Schema.org/Event type, however I need to add contact person name and phone but which property of Event can I use for that? I used "performer" property, but that is not really it...

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    <span class="time"><time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2012-07-02T19:00:00">19:00</time></span>
    <h2 class="colored" itemprop="name">Worship Group</h2>
    <strong>Address:</strong> <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" class="dashed" title="See on the map"><span itemprop="location">St. Patric 42</span></a>
    <br><strong>Contacts:</strong>
    <span itemprop="performer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <span itemprop="telephone">8-422-212-5532</span> (<span itemprop="name">John Parker</span>)</span>
    <span itemprop="description">We want to worhip God together</span>
</div>
```

As for a house church - it's something between an Organization and Event - it's a group of believers getting together at a place at a certain time. I decided to go for http://schema.org/Organization, added ContactPoint as church leader contacts info. But how can I mark start time?

Is there any way to combine entity types so that I could describe all important properties I have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First part of your question:**

> *For schedule I decided to go for http://Schema.org/Event type, however
>   I need to add contact person name and phone but which property of
>   Event can I use for that?*

You're spot on using an `Event` for your schedules. You could of course be a bit more precise and and use an extension of `Event` to be more precise as itemtype.

When you wish to specify a contact person as a performer I'm a bit unsure. I would rather flip your thinking around and not specify a contact person but instead specify the events as upcoming or past events associated with the organization. The organization then has a contact point that will go for all the events.

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization/ReligiousGroup">
  <div itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Church">
    ...
  </div>

  <div itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    ...
  </div>

  <div itemprop="events" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    ...
  </div>

  <div itemprop="events" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    ...
  </div>

  <div itemprop="events" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Or more simple described with YAML:

```
--- 
Organization/ReligiousGroup:
  location : Church
  contactPoint : Person
  events : 
    - Event
    - Event
    - Event
```

You can extend `Organization` to `ReligiousGroup` to be more precise of the item.

Read more about extending here: http://www.schema.org/docs/extension.html

---

**Now the final part of your question:**

> *As for a house church - it's something between an Organization and
>   Event - it's a group of believers getting together at a place at a
>   certain time.*

A group of people getting together at a place at a certain time is an `Event`.

Comment: Thanks, Erik, I really appreciate your answer. However, we have different contacts for each event so specifying one ContactPoint is not a good solution. Second off, Organization has mandatory name property, but it does not appear on the page. Of course I can specify it using meta but search engines don't like it when we want them to parse information that cannot be viewed on the page. So it seems like I should better omit contacts information in this case.

Comment: Yep, this is the only supported way I can figure out though. The next best thing would probably be to extend the attendees property, like so: attendees/contactPerson.

Comment: ..and about that "meta stuff isn't good for SEO" you wrote. I don't agree that meta data would be harmful in a SEO perspective. I understand way you may think so, but there's an difference between defining something with a span wrapper that has a CSS property of display:none and declaring something as meta data. Meta is an html standard and I have serious doubts that this would be considered a no-no by Google.

Comment: Using the attendee property instead of performer is a real good idea, wonder why it did not come to my mind? As for meta data - I decided to put the content that appears in meta in the title attribute of one of the blocks, so actually this info can be seen by the user. Thanks for you help, Edik, I owe you one ;-)

Comment: I think your edit yesterday is great. I've deleted the comments that were above as they are now obsolete. Appreciate your effort to adjust it for potential reader sensitivity.